# Raspberry pi time wrong

Tags: pi-2, ntp

My raspberry Pi 2 has a wrong date and it is not a timezone problem since UTC time right now is (6:53 PM Thursday, June 2, 2016) and running:

```
pi@raspberrypi2:~ $ date -u
mié jun  1 14:13:45 UTC 2016
```

Also, see this:

```
pi@raspberrypi2:~ $ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 ntp.copaco.com. .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 190.15.128.72   .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 c.ntp.br        .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 234.229.33.186. .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

What i get from tha output is that, apparently, since the offset is 0 then raspbian thinks its time is perfect and it doesn't change it to the right value.

Any clues here?
Thanks!

**EDIT1:** I do have interent connection, I can ping servers and get responses, also DNS is properly configured, I can sucessfully use nslookup

Comment: Are you sure you have an internet connection? Normally it will display a + or * in the first column for the peers.

Comment: @SteveRobillard yes it does have internet access. I can ping those servers and get a response

Comment: As your own answer confirms, in the above output from `ntpq -p` the second column suggests that the connections to the listed servers have not been fully set up (and in your case blocked).  You might like to note that when `ntpd` is up and running it tracks the last 20-odd periodic packets from each peer and the status of those is indicated in the "when" column (which contains an incrementing count of, usually seconds since the last packet/poll) "poll" is the interval between those poll attempts and "reach" is a two and a half octal digit bitmap of those 20 packets obtained: 377 good, 0 bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out my ISP blocked port 125.

I followed this guide: 
[HOWTO: Run Your Own NTP Server When Your ISP Blocks Ports](https://brainwreckedtech.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/howto-run-your-own-ntp-server-when-your-isp-blocks-ports/)

Which explains how to use ntpdate on a non blocked port.

Thanks @Karim and @SteveRobillard

Answer (score 2):

If your Raspberry is running Ubuntu you can run this command

```
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

and it will update the time automatically according to ubuntu time server, However if you want Ubuntu to update the time after each reboot

create a file **/etc/cron.daily/ntpdate** that contain

```
#!/bin/sh
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Make sure that you make this new file executable:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/ntpdate
```

And thats it.

Comment: Can this command be changed for other OS's?

Comment: This command is included with so many linux distributions so it should work for other OS's.

Comment: What i meant was more like if i did use a different OS would i still use `ntp.ubuntu.com` or some other place?

Comment: that should work fine or you can go to [NTP Website](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/StratumOneTimeServers) and chose the one that suits you

Comment: The raspberryPi is headless, running the latest raspbian jessie lite (From May 2016), it doesnt seem to have that ntpdate command :(

Comment: @Karim I apt-get'ed that command and ran it. It complained, saying "the NTP socket is in use, exiting" so I stopped ntp "sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop" to free the socket and re-ran "sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com". It says "ntpdate[2027]: no server suitable for synchronization found"

Comment: @seed_87 Your hosting provider is blocking ntp packets. This heavy handed approach has been implemented by some ISPs in response to the DDoS attacks, try using VPN